# De-interleave an array in place?

Tags: c++, arrays

Lets say I have an array of interlaced data, such as 1a2b3c4d5e, and I want to de-interlace it into an array that looks like 12345abcde, in place (without a temporary buffer). What would be the fastest way of doing this?

What I have so far is this

```
template<typename T>
void deinterlace(T* arr, int length){
  if(length<=1) return;

  int i = 1;
  for(i = 1; i*2<length; i++){
    //swap i with i*2
    T temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[i*2];
    arr[i*2] = temp;
  }
  deinterlace(arr+i, length-i);
}
```

which unfortunately doesn't work with arrays not a power of 2 in size

**edit**: this algo fails at larger powers of 2 anyway so I guess I'm at square 0 again

**edit 2**: I have found an nlogn algorithm for this, given either an O(n) array rotate function, or an initial size which is a power of 2

works like so:

1a2b3c4d5e6f7g, "chunk size" = 1 initial,

split into groups of chunk size *4
1a2b 3c4d 5e6f 7g

swap the inner 2 chunks of each group
12ab 34cd 56ef 7g

repeat with chunk size = chunk size *2

12ab34cd 56ef7g (read: 56 ef 7 g) ->
1234abcd 567efg

1234abcd567efg ->
1234567abcdefg

```
template<typename T>
void deinterlace(T* arr, int length, int group_ct = 1){
  if(group_ct*2 >= length) return;

  for(int i = 0; i<length; i+=group_ct*4){
    int rot_count = group_ct;

    int i1 = i + group_ct;
    int i2 = i+group_ct*4 - group_ct;

    if(i2+group_ct > length){
      i2 = i1 + (length-i1)/2+group_ct/2;
    }

    rotate(arr, i1, i2, group_ct);

  }

  deinterlace(arr, length, group_ct * 2);
}
```

**edit 3** I guess the correct term is deinterleave, not deinterlace

Comment: In general, this is not a trivial task to do in place. This is very common in DSP algorithms and there's been quite a bit of research on how to do this efficiently. Maybe this case has an easy efficient solution. I'll wait for someone to prove me wrong.

Comment: yeah it's for an audio engine. I suppose I could pad the initial array out to a power of 2, but then I'm wasting space and may as well use a temporary.

Comment: @GlaielGamer padding to the nearest power may be **much** smaller than doubling the array, depending on the size of chunks (take 60 or 4000).

Comment: Do you know the size of the array ahead of time? Is it constant, or one of a small number of constants?

Comment: well yeah, but the padded version would stay in memory forever, whereas a temp could be freed after its use is done.

Comment: also, the algo I discovered doesnt work on powers of two over like 16 (I misread the output)

Comment: I think you mean *deinterleave*?

Comment: yeah i mean deinterleave, my bad

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is essentially a matrix transposition problem. Your array

```
[1 a]
[2 b]
[3 c]
[4 d]
```

is equivalent to  `1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, d` if represented as a vector (by reading rows first). The transpose of this matrix is:

```
[1 2 3 4]
[a b c d]
```

which is equivalent to `1, 2, 3, 4, a, b, c, d`.

There is a [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition) that deals with in-place matrix transposition for the general cases. I guess, the algorithm for non-square matrix would be directly applicable.

---

There is a slow (not sure if O(n^2) or worse, and it is late) algorithm that you can use. The idea is to in place rotate the sub-array from position `i` to position `2*i`. For example:

```
START: 1a2b3c4d5e6f
1(a2)...         -> 1(2a)...
12(ab3)...       -> 12(3ab)...
123(abc4)...     -> 123(4abc)...
1234(abcd5)...   -> 1234(5abcd)...
12345(abcde6)... -> 12345(6abcde)..
123456(abcdef)   -> DONE
```

The first member of the array is index 0. At step 1, you select the sub-array `a[1:2]`, and rotate it right (all members go to next location, and the last one goes to start). Next step, you select `a[2:4]`, and rotate that, etc. Make sure you don't rotate the last sub-array `a[n/2:n]`.

---

And a final option, if you do not need to do bulk operations for performance (such as `memcpy`), is to provide an accessor function, and transform the index instead of moving any bytes. Such a function is almost trivial to write: if index is less than `max/2`, return entry at `2*index`, otherwise, return entry at `2*(index-max/2)+1`.

Comment: Ok thanks, this is exactly what I need. Well not really what I need, but knowing it can't really be done without temporary storage is a satisfying enough answer too.

Comment: in regards to your edit: yeah n^2 is too slow for an array that is megabytes in size

Comment: @GlaielGamer That's the best I can come up with so far. I will update the answer if I can think of anything better.

Comment: Yeah its still an interesting problem but I found a workaround for what I needed it for

Answer (score 3):

Your original idea will *almost* work for an in-place deinterleave. You just need to account for the fact that when you swap an item into place, you displace the item that the formula expects to find there.

So first, define the `source_index` function:  given a perfectly interleaved array of length `N` and an index `i`, return the item that should be in `i`.  The first half comes from every other even item, the last half from every other odd item.

```
int source_index(int i, int length) {
  int mid = length-length/2;

  if (i<mid) {
    return i*2;
  }
  return (i-mid)*2+1;
}
```

Now you can walk through the array swapping items into place.  But if you find a source index that is less than the current target index, you need to re-do the calculation to find out where it was swapped to.

```
template<typename T>
void deinterlace(T* arr, int length){
  if(length<=1) return;

  int i = 1;
  for(i = 1; i<length; i++){
    int j = source_index(i, length);
    while (j<i) { //walk the chain of swaps
      j = source_index(j, length);
    }
    T temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
  }
}
```

This does exactly N swaps. The number of calls to `source_index` is somewhat chaotic, but seems to exhibit NlgN growth.[image: Plot of N vs <code>next_index</code> operations]

Comment: This is brilliant! One optimisation that could be done is doing all the multiplications by 2 at the same time with a single bitshift: <https://wandbox.org/permlink/3qEUWMOAbBW5T6gQ> Also, from plotting, it seems that the time taken is between O(n^1.118) and O(n^1.13), so worse than O(n lg n). However, for deinterleaving 1GiB of chars, calculating the indices took ~1billion operations and took less than a millisecond (most time was spent swapping), so for reasonable amounts of data (<1TiB), this is essentially O(n)

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  
If you are interested in going the other way, I describe a related algorithm here ( https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/105604/58310).     By the way, your link appears to be broken.

Comment: Here's a different link that should work: https://godbolt.org/z/Pjrn6YGsx . Plotting the number of times the loop is done with x at the log scale did not show a straight line, but on a log-log scale it seemed linear, implying it's exponential

Answer (score -1):

If you **don't care about the order** of the resultant array, the fastest way I can think of is to do successive swaps using a 'head' and 'tail' index.

```
int head = 1;
int tail = length - 2;
while (head < tail)
{
    T temp = arr[head];
    temp = arr[head];
    arr[head] = arr[tail];
    arr[tail] = temp;
    head += 2;
    tail -= 2;
}
```

For your example case, the result would be 15243cbdae after 2 iterations.

Comment: Then sort the two halves as a second stpe

Comment: They aren't supposed to be sorted, just in the same order they were in the original array, i.e. if the array was KZUHYDIA the result should be KUYIZHDA