# In place algorithm for string transformation

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

Given a string, move all digit elements to end of string. While moving elements, keep the relative order of all positioned elements same.

For example, if the given string is

> a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j1k2l3m4

convert it to

> abcdefghijklm1234567891234

in-place and in O(n) time complexity.

I got a different result

> abcdefghijklm7481951326324

Also I failed for testing another string

> aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nZWVrc2ZvcmdlZWtzLm9yZy9hbi1pbi1wbGFjZS1hbGdvcml0aG0tZm9yLXN0cmluZy10cmF

Code:

```
    static string s = "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j1k2l3m4";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] input = s.ToCharArray();
        string output = arrangeList(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.WriteLine("Another test");
        s = "aHR0cDovL3d3dy5nZWVrc2ZvcmdlZWtzLm9yZy9hbi1pbi1wbGFjZS1hbGdvcml0aG0tZm9yLXN0cmluZy10cmF";
        input = s.ToCharArray();
        output = arrangeList(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static string arrangeList(char[] x)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < x.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            while (j < x.Length)
            {
                if ( (x[j] > '0' && x[j] < '9') && x[i] > '9')
                {
                    swap(x, i, j); j++;
                    break;
                }
                if ( (x[i] > '0' && x[i] < '9') && x[j] > '9')
                {
                    swap(x, i, j); j++;
                    break;
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        return new string(x);
    }
    private static void swap(char[] a, int i, int j)
    {
        char temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Why is it important that it is in place?

Comment: Never mind, yeah. It doesn't matter. Sorry for it. But I wish that there is another in-place algorithm.

Comment: Why down vote? Please provide me a reason. Originally it was an in place alrorithm question at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/an-in-place-algorithm-for-string-transformation/. I just modified it.

Comment: @Love - Why did you tag the question with "linq", but give the answer to a non-linq solution? Especially when you have two excellent linq solutions?

Comment: @Enigmativity, I am not sure linq's complexity. I hope there is a generic algorithm if I use other language alough tagged c# and linq.

Comment: @Enigmativity: One of the LINQ solutions doesn't work, and the other has O(n log n) complexity.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move all odd positioned element to left half and even positioned to right half in-place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338654/move-all-odd-positioned-element-to-left-half-and-even-positioned-to-right-half-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build it in a character array pretty easily by working from the back to copy digits and from the front to copy letters. That is:

```
var input = "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j1k2l3m4";
int ixLetter = 0;
int ixDigit = input.Length - 1;
int oxLetter = 0;
int oxDigit = input.Length - 1;

char[] output = new char[input.Length];
while (ixDigit >= 0)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(input[ixDigit]))
    {
        output[oxDigit] = input[ixDigit];
        --oxDigit;
    }
    if (!char.IsDigit(input[ixLetter]))
    {
        output[oxLetter] = input[ixLetter];
        ++oxLetter;
    }
    --ixDigit;
    ++ixLetter;
}

string result = new string(output);
```

This does two passes over the string, one from the front and one from the back. Complexity is linear, thus O(n).

Now, doing it in a single pass ... I'd have to think a bit about that.

Comment: this algorithm violates in-place property. size of the output arrays is n, so this is O(n) space complexity.

Answer (score 3):

With Linq

```
var input = "a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j1k2l3m4";
var output = String.Join("", input.GroupBy(c => char.IsDigit(c))
                                  .OrderBy(x => x.Key) //Always 2 items to sort. Not O(N*logN)
                                  .SelectMany(g => g));
```

Comment: @NiklasB. `My definition`? Are you *Love* or *NiklasB* ? BTW: you convert your string to char array. So you don't do it in-place too.

Comment: Well since OP has revised his requirement of in-placeness, I removed my comments as they are no longer relevant. +1 for a pragrmatic approach

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if the beginning string is `"1ab2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j1k2l3m4"`, the numbers are at the front of the string rather than at the end.

Comment: This is easily fixed with a `.OrderBy(x => x.Key)` after the `GroupBy`. This wouldn't be O(n) though, but how big could the input string to make the efficiency an issue?

Answer (score 1):

This works, uses linq, and has O(n) time complexity:

```
var input = @"123vcvcv00191pololo";
var array =
    input
        .ToCharArray()
        .Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c))
        .Concat(
            input
                .ToCharArray()
                .Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)))
        .ToArray();
var output = new String(array);

Console.Write(output);
// vcvcvpololo12300191
```

Comment: `ToCharArray()` isn't necessary. `String` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

using linq's OrderBy as shown should move all the digits to the end of the string/char[] in the order in which they appear in the string.

```
var input  = @"123vcvcv00191pololo";
var array  = input.ToCharArray().OrderBy(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();
var output = new String(array);

Console.Write(output);
//vcvpololo12300191
```

Comment: An interesting solution, but it has O(n log n) time complexity. OP asked for O(n).