# Array size in Cycle leader iteration Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

why is the array divided into size 3^k+1 for any non-negative integer k for the Cycle leader iteration Algorithm?

Comment: What does this have to do with C++, or programming at all? Looks like a purely algorithmic question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12339432/5008845

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I've spent the past half day working through it. The paper actually describes an algorithm for a slightly different problem than the one that I think that this question talks about, and for a while I thought that 3^k + 1 was incorrect before I started looking more closely. I actually don't think that the arXiv paper does a good job talking about how the algorithm works; it leaves a *lot* to the reader.