# Deinterleave odd and even entries of vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

Is there a one liner (or a simple loop-free) solution to de-interleave the odd and even entries of a vector?
Example:

```
long entries[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
std::vector<long> vExample(entries, entries + sizeof(entries) / sizeof(long) );

vExample.intertwine(vExample.begin(),vExample.end()); // magic one liner I wish existed...

for (int i = 0; i < vExample.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << vExample[i] << " ";
}
```

Now I'd like to have the following output:

```
0 2 4 6 1 3 5 7
```

Comment: That is really not what I would expect something called `intertwine()` to do ... On the other hand I don't know a better name. :) And why not just write a loop and put it inside a function?

Comment: Using stable sort algorithm with comparator doing something like `if (odd) return value; else return value*100000000`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7780279/10396 for an in-place solution.  You'll have to wrap it in a one-liner yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) or [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition), depending on whether you need the order of the elements preserved:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> vals {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    std::stable_partition(begin(vals), end(vals), [](auto i){return !(i % 2);});
    for (auto v : vals)
        std::cout << v << " ";
}
```

Output: `0 2 4 6 1 3 5 7`. See it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/466dfcfef802a40e).

You can of course partition by any other criterion by changing the predicate.

Comment: Why does it work with the example vector, but not with, for example, {0,1,2,10,11}? It that case I'd expect {0,2,11,1,10}, but I get {0,2,10,1,11}.

Comment: @dpgomez I don't quite understand your new example. As I understood your question, you want to put all even numbers in the front and all odd numbers in the back, which is what this does. If that is not what you want, please clarify the question.

Comment: Why would you expect 10 to be partitioned as if odd?  You must not have given a clear description of the problem.

Comment: I would like the odd and even vector indices to be resorted. In my example the entries are identical to the indices. Is it better to edit the question or ask a new one?

Comment: @dpgomez Aha. This is not at all how I (or anyone else afaics) understood this question. Maybe you should post a new question where you clearly ask how to partition a vector by indices. All the answers here solve the "partition based on the *entries*" problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::partition(std::begin(vExample), std::end(vExample), [](long l) { return !(l%2); });
```

Of course, `partition` has loop(s) in it.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition

Comment: I was writing an answer using a `for` loop along with moving the elements after looking at their indices, but this one takes the cake. One learns something everyday on SO. :)

Comment: caveat: `Relative order of the elements is not preserved.`. It looks like the OP wants this order preserved.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < vExample.size() * 2; i += 2) {
    auto value = vExample[i%vExample.size()];
    //Do whatever you want with value, print it out, etc.
    if(i == vExample.size() - 2) i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard algorithm `std::stable_partition` declared in header `<algorithm>`. For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

long entries[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
std::vector<long> vExample(entries, entries + sizeof(entries) / sizeof(long) );

std::stable_partition( vExample.begin(), vExample.end(), []( long x ) { return x % 2 == 0; } );

for ( long x : vExample ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The output is

```
0 2 4 6 1 3 5 7
```